# C# ExcelLibary get a Word

Tags: c#

I just wanna know
how I can get a Word in line A1 cell A1.

Is there a way to get it without having excel installed?
Just using Excellibary?

Thanks for helping! :)

Comment: What did you try?how did you fail?

Comment: I do try to get the column of a datagridview

Comment: OK but how? what did you try? show the code, explain how it didnt work.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < data.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                string temp2 = data.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
                int nummer = i;

                if (temp2.Equals("Hersteller"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("YAY");
                }

            }

How can I on which cell it was?

Comment: Well you know the value of i right?? so you know where you were...

Comment: No I do not know...int nummer = i; will update every second to a higher number

Comment: but if you find the word - you know what i is... as I said

Comment: I just started coding and know ;D