# C#, for loop & columname

Tags: c#

I want to get the cell number of the column "Hersteller".
I don't know how to do that and thought anyth

```
int columnIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
tring columnName = dataGridView1.Columns[columnIndex].Name;

for(columnName.Equals("Hersteller") columnIndex++;) { }
```

any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# ExcelLibary get a Word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869341/c-sharp-excellibary-get-a-word)

Comment: A columns does not have a cellnumber, as it has a list of cells.

Comment: You already have a question on this and the above code doesnt compile

Comment: How to make that work @HimBromBeere ?

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the columns and get the index:

```
int colIndex = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name.Equals("Hersteller"))
    {
        colIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (colIndex > -1)
    // Found the column, do something
```

Comment: Works fine! Thanks!